# The appendChild method does not insert the element into the body

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

In my example, I'm trying to fetch data from the server and save it to the document as text in the <p> element. Everything works fine except that the appendChild method doesn't seem to work as it should. Here is a sample of my code and the error message:

```js
(async () => {
    let resp = await fetch("/shaders", {
        method: "GET"
    });
    let txt = await resp.text();
    let elm = document.createElement("p").innerHTML = txt;

    console.log(txt) // Hello Stack Overflow!
    // logs the message as expected
    document.body.appendChild(elm)
    // error occurs
})()
```

With error message: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object,** at line 10.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

--

*Note: With the append method it works just fine*

Comment: That's because elm is the result of that statement ... i.e. the string txt ... and appendChild expects an element whereas append can work with string

Comment: I see, so appendChild must be an empty element and I have to add text to it after I append it, but the append method also works with the text in the element if I understand it correctly?

Comment: No. It has to be an element. The issue is what elem is. It's not an element, since you didn't assign an element to it

Comment: Ooh, I get it now. True I was only saving text itself instead of an element that's why it didn't work for me. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN docs on the JavaScript assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment):

> Chaining the assignment operator is possible in order to assign a single value to multiple variables.

So,

```js
let elm = document.createElement("p").innerHTML = txt;

// The above has the same effect as doing the following:
document.createElement("p").innerHTML = txt;
let elm = txt;
```

`elm` gets assigned text, which [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) does not accept as an argument type (although `Element.append` does, which you noticed but perhaps didn't fully understand why).

I'm guessing you intended to do this:

```js
let elm = document.createElement("p");
elm.textContent = txt;
```

Note that I used `Node.textContent` instead of `Element.innerHTML`. The [MDN docs state the differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innerhtml)

> Element.innerHTML returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes people use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element, but textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML.
>
> Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

If you really need to use `innerHTML` or `innerText` *and* the resource you are fetching is not always controlled by you, you probably want to do some kind of sanitization to protect against XSS.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // i use json placeholder api just for test you can keep your default methode to get data
        (async () => {
            let resp = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => data.title)
            let txt = await resp;

            let node = document.createElement("p")
            let elm = document.createTextNode(txt)

            node.appendChild(elm)

            document.body.appendChild(node)
        })()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The Fetch API for CORS is deprecated, fetch must use a http or https link.

Comment: “The Fetch API for CORS is deprecated” - That what now?

Comment: “fetch must use a http or https link” — Do you have some reason to think that the relative URL provided does not resolve to an HTTP(S) URI?

Comment: this is untrue. Fetch has support for CORS. As of now, we can use Fetch to send requests CORS. Also, in node.js, you don't really have to use CORS at all, unless to access resources blocked even to browsers.